# How can I concatenate objects from a string with a semicolon in between?

Tags: c#

I have a list that I traverse as follows:

```
foreach (var obj in mylist)
{
    return += obj.Value.ToString() + ";";
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Do I need a `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is not working because you are concatenating your string with [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return) which is keyword in C#.

Initialize `StringBuilder` append your value to it with semicolon.

Like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var obj in mylist)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0};", obj.Value);
}

return sb.ToString();
```

---

Elegant way is to use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) where you pass `string` with an  IEnumerable @TheGeneral gave you solution to use `string.Join()` i.e.

```
var result = string.Join(";", mylist.Select(x => x.Value));
```

where `;` is your separator and `mylist.Select()` will return  `IEnumerable` of Values which will return same result as your first approach.

Comment: Also `sb.AppendFormat("{0};", obj.Value);`

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks for your suggestion. I was not aware of this function of `StringBuilder` class. I updated my answer. Everyday is a school day ;)

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I don't see advantage to use AppendFormat if you could explain please? personally, I always used string.Join, or if I really need a for/foreach I just use a string, then instead of `sb.AppendFormat("{0};", obj.Value);` I do `myString+=separator+obj.Value`, so don't need StringBuilder(Didn't even knows it exists until today).

Comment: @Siegfried.V, If you check my code I used formatted string with `;` i.e `{0};`. OP wants `;` after each `obj.Value`, so instead of concatenating obj.Value with `;` using `+` I used `AppendFormat()` function of `StringBuilder`. It gives you cleaner way to do the concatenation of strings.

Comment: @Siegfried.V, regarding your second point, `myString+=separator+obj.Value` if we consider `myString` is of type `string` then **string is immutable** it will create new instance of string every time, if you iterate 100 times then It will allocate memory 100 times. To avoid this I used `StringBuilder`, you can read about string vs stringBuilder in C# this will give you more insights on why I did not use `myString+=separator+obj.Value`

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar I suggest to iterate 1 million times. This can give a **really** good idea why StringBuilder is used instead of string concatenation (which are all left dead in the mud, waiting for garbage collection).

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar ok, so if I understood, this is for Memory reasons, until now I concatenate from 2 to 10 strings so it may not be problematic, but good to know for future, thanks for explainations

Answer (score 5):

You could just use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
>   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.

and [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

```
return string.Join(";", mylist.Select(x => x.Value));
```